# Using UIWebView with preset address as option for physical goods payment in app

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, payment

We have an application that facilitates selling physical goods (auction style).

I've been searching through forums and only found out, that I should not use StoreKit, but other means of payment (like card.io, ZooZ, PayPal API). My problem with this is that most of our customers probably don't have PayPal account including in regions like Eastern Europe.

Do you know, if there is an option, in which after successful purchase, my app will open `UIWebView` with preset data (like internet banking portal with filled fields e.g. amount to pay, variable symbol, customer name)?
I read somewhere, that using `UIWebView` will get my app rejected and I should open Safari browser, but people's opinions vary in this.

Could someone who has experience or had his app approved using UIWebView please respond? I've read apple guidelines for at least 10 times, but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I read somewhere, that using UIWebView will get my app rejected and I
>   should open safari browser

Apple will not reject an app just because it uses `UIWebView`.

> Do you know, if there is an option, in which after successful
>   purchase, my app will open UIWebView with preset data

You can probably use this method: `- (NSString *)stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:(NSString *)script`